# Express - Replace middleware on runtime

Tags: node.js, express, runtime, middleware

I'm using Express and I would like to replace a middleware **on runtime** (stop running middleware X and start running middleware Y).
I found an easy way to do it, but no one here is giving it as an option:

Instead of using the first middleware, xMiddleware:

```
app.use(xMiddleware);
```

I'm wrapping it with another middleware, MyMiddlewareWrap:

```
MyMiddleware = xMiddleware; 

MyMiddlewareWrap = function (req, res, next) 
{
    MyMiddleware(req, res, next)
}

app.use(MyMiddlewareWrap);
```

Then, when I want to stop running xMiddleware and start running yMiddleware, I'm assigning yMiddleware to MyMiddleware:

```
MyMiddleware = yMiddleware;
```

As a result, xMiddleware doesn't run anymore and yMiddleware is running instead.
Does anyone see a problem with it? Is it a good solution?

Comment: Interesting. Upvoting. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

While reading your question I thought exactly to your solution.

Yes, it should achieve the desired result without any problem.